# ¿Cómo conocer la etiqueta seleccionada con querySelector?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Si yo tengo esta etiqueta html:

```html
<div class="conteiner"></div>
```

y la selecciono así:

```js
let conteiner = document.querySelector(".conteiner");
```

¿De que forma puedo comprobar si ese elemento es un div? Porque si hago esto:

```js
typeof conteiner;
```

Solo va a decir que es un 'object', pero no se que propiedad de ese objeto puedo utilizar para conocer si etiqueta HTML.

Comment: Puedes saber la etiqueta usada buscándola por nombre: [element.tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName)

Answer (score 0):

Después de hacer un volcado con console.log de `conteiner` y analizar sus propiedades, he encontrado al menos tres propiedades que contienen `div`.

A saber:

1. **localName**: Tal como dice su [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/localName):

> La propiedad únicamente de lectura Element.localName devuelve la parte
> local del nombre calificado de un objeto.
>
> Antes de DOM4 esta API fué definida dentro de la interfazNode.

```
conteiner.localName
```

Veo que en este caso lo devuelve en minúsculas, y creo que es porque se utiliza en salidas XML, donde todo es en minúsculas.

2. **nodeName**. Tal como dice su [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName):

> Devuelve el nombre del nodo actual, en forma de cadena.

```
conteiner.nodeName
```

3. **tagName**. Tal como dice su [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName):

> Devuelve el nombre del elemento.

```
conteiner.tagName
```

Pero en este caso dice algo más:

> En XML (y los lenguajes basados en XML tales como XHTML) el código
> tagName es sensible a las mayúsculas. En HTML, tagName devuelve el
> nombre del elemento en forma canonica, es decir con todas sus letras
> en mayúscula. El valor del código of tagName es el mismo que el de la
> instrucción nodeName.

Por lo tanto, deduzco que:

```
valor de tagName = valor de nodeName = MAYÚSCULAS
valor de localName = MINÚSCULAS
```

Y aquí un dejo un snippet con las tres propiedades sacadas por consola:

```js
let conteiner = document.querySelector(".conteiner");
console.log('localName: ' + conteiner.localName)
console.log('nodeName: ' + conteiner.nodeName)
console.log('tagname: ' + conteiner.tagName)
```

```html
<div class="conteiner"></div>
```